# Using an include inside an echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert this search form into my wordpress header. I found where php calls for the user-uploaded logo, and would like to insert the form immediately after.

Search form include:

```
<?php include ('wp-content/themes/thematic/searchform.php'); ?>
```

Functions.php echo:

```
function childtheme_override_blogtitle(){

    global $up_options;

    echo '<div id="blog-title"><span><a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/" title="' . get_bloginfo('name') . '" rel="home"><img src="' . $up_options->logo . '" alt="" /></a></span></div>';

}

add_action('thematic_header','childtheme_override_blogtitle',3);

function childtheme_override_blogdescription(){
```

I tried inserting the form as a separate div, but this keeps the form from centering with the rest of the main content.  So I am trying insert the form where php creates the div. You can see my current progress here: texturly.com

Comment: *Just to be clear, I am asking this question because I can't figure out how to add the include into the echo (or after but inside the same div) via php. I'm a complete noob!

Comment: Instead of moving your include around, why not make the contents of that include a function, and then call that function where you want?

Comment: I'd be more than happy to do that, but I literally don't know how. I'm so new to php that I don't know how to write that include or function into the "blog-title" div. Is there any way you could provide me with a sample code of how that would look? It would be a big help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function for including the theme's searchform..
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form

Just call it inside your function or appropriate file.

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

There's an example filter on the above codex page to, should you want to override searchform markup from within your functions file.

**EDIT:** Regarding placement inside the function, i'd write it a little something like this.

```
function childtheme_override_blogtitle(){
    global $up_options;
    ?>

    <div id="blog-title">
        <span><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $up_options->logo; ?>" alt="" /></a></span>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

Of course move that search form where you want it, i just reformatted how the HTML is generated so you'll have an easier time adjusting it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this, t31os. As i said above, I'm lost on how to actually execute this function into the "blog-title" div. Could you show me how that code would look? Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I genuinely appreciate it!                           I went with your code, but created another div inside "blog-title" so I could style it with css.  Thanks again!